# how to DIAGNOSE a db2 "SQL0964C" The transaction log for the database is full

Tags: db2

I know how to RESOLVE the problem, but I do not have any idea, how to find the cause/source (f.e. which statement) of the problem. Where (table, tools, commands) to look.

can I see something in the excerpt from db2diag.log?

```
2015-06-24-09.23.29.190320+120 ExxxxxxxxxE530     LEVEL: Error
PID     : 15972                TID  : 1           PROC : db2agent (XXX) 0
INSTANCE: db2inst2             NODE : 000         DB   : XXX
APPHDL  : 0-4078               APPID: xxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx
AUTHID  : XXX     
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data protection services, sqlpgResSpace, probe:2860
MESSAGE : ADM1823E  The active log is full and is held by application handle 
          "3308".  Terminate this application by COMMIT, ROLLBACK or FORCE 
          APPLICATION.
```

Answer (score 5):

The `db2diag.log` shows you the agent ID (application handle) of the application causing the problem (`3308`).

Provided you are seeing this in real time (as opposed to looking at `db2diag.log` after the fact), you can:

1. Use `db2top` to view information about this connection
2. Query `sysibmadm.snapstmt` (looking at `stmt_text` and `agent_id`)
3. Use `db2pd -activestatements` and `db2pd -dynamic` (keying on `AnchID` and `StmtUID`
4. Use good old `get snapshot for application`

There are also many 3rd party tools that can also give you the information you are looking for.

Comment: thank you very much, I learned something new. I will report, what helped, when/if the problem arises again, as it only pops up sproadically